# Ubuntu install PHP couchbase extension

Tags: linux, ubuntu, couchbase

I run composer install for new project and I got eror:

```
the requested PHP extension couchbase is missing from your system. To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
```

So I was trying to intall couchbase SDK from official website:

```
# Only needed during first-time setup:
wget http://packages.couchbase.com/releases/couchbase-release/couchbase-release-1.0-4-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i couchbase-release-1.0-4-amd64.deb
# Will install or upgrade packages
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcouchbase-dev libcouchbase2-bin build-essential
```

after sudo dpkg -i couchbase-release-1.0-4-amd64.deb i got error:

```
    (Reading database ... 155822 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack couchbase-release-1.0-4-amd64.deb ...
Supported platforms are: Debian/wheezy,jessie and Ubuntu/lucid,precise,trusty,xenial

dpkg: error processing archive couchbase-release-1.0-4-amd64.deb (--install):
 new couchbase-release package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 couchbase-release-1.0-4-amd64.deb
```

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and PHP 7.1

Comment: I think that Bionic isn't supported by libcouchbase yet (it's not in the repos for 18 as far as I can see) which is what the PHP SDK is built on top of, I'd guess that's why it's failing. You could try to build from source though (https://github.com/couchbase/php-couchbase and https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase), I just did that on an ubuntu 18.04 machine and it worked fine.

Comment: I have installed libcouchbase then tried to install php-couchbase but got an error: checking for libcouchbase in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the libcouchbase distribution -
                 libcouchbase.h should be <libcouchbase-dir>/include and
                 libcouchbase.a should be in <libcouchbase-dir>/lib

Comment: you have to install libcouchbase. version 2.9.0 supports bionic and stretch

Comment: it worked but after make && make install Im getting Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/user/Downloads/php-couchbase/modules/couchbase.so' - /home/user/Downloads/php-couchbase/modules/couchbase.so: undefined symbol: json_globals in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I am having same issue, was your issue resolved? If yes, please let me know how.

Comment: @avsej How to install specific version 2.9.0?

Comment: @Nabeel, depending what system do you have, for example on Fedora Linux, it is in official repository (along with php extension), for others you might want to use  our own repositories, or you can use tarballs. More info at https://developer.couchbase.com/server/other-products/release-notes-archives/c-sdk